# What to configure, when Tomcat gladly accepts a 480 MB upload, but not much more even without maxsize restrictions?

Tags: java, tomcat

When I'm uploading a zipfile to a servlet as a *multipart/form-data*, its parts will be available when the file size is about 480 MB or less, but when the filesize is about 506 MB or more, *req.getParts().size()* is zero.

The Tomcat server seems to use the configuration values, which are set in files server.xml and application's web.xml. I tried to set relevant max sizes to "-1", but to no avail as I couldn't upload a file that is slightly larger than 0.5 GB or so.

**server.xml** - Connector has these values:

```
maxPostSize="-1"
maxHttpHeaderSize="65536"
disableUploadTimeout="true"
protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
```

**web.xml** - servlet's multipart-config has these values:

```
<max-file-size>-1</max-file-size>
<max-request-size>-1</max-request-size>
```

What other configuration needs to be done to make Tomcat to not drop parts that are too large? Other parts aren't left out. E.g. the value of the "dfgdfgd" in the example would still be available, when doing req.getPart("dfgdfgd");

```
var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("dfgdfg", "dfgdfgd");
formdata.append("filedata", filedata);

$.ajax({
    url: servletpath,
    method: "POST",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formdata
}).done(function(data) {
```

I was going to process "filedata" part in a later phase by retrieving it using req.getPart("filedata") and BufferedInputStream, but too large files cause problems as the req.getPart("filedata") would be just null.

I'm using Tomcat 9, Servlet Spec 4.0. I'm using protocol "Http11NioProtocol", because Eclipse can't start Tomcat, when it is set as "Http11Nio2Protocol".

Comment: If you are using Tomcat from within Eclipse, try a separate stock install of Tomcat (unzip) and run the web app. Check the logs and see if you are getting any exceptions, warnings, that might give more details of the issue.